# Add github run number to a file in github repo

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to add the github run number to a file in the github repository. The file looks like the following:

```
import json
from importlib import reload
import hashlib
from logging import raiseExceptions
import os
import importlib

qwe = importlib.import_module("asd-64")
```

The `64` signifies the github run number. I have tried doing the following:

```
qwe = importlib.import_module("asd-${{ github.run_number }}")
```

This doesn't work and prints the string `${{ github.run_number }}`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it using a **python script** and **placeholders**. *(It might not be the best solution, but at least it works!)*

The file to update would look like this:

`test.py`

```py
import json
from importlib import reload
import hashlib
from logging import raiseExceptions
import os
import importlib

#placeholder1
```

The script to update it would look like this:

`update_file.py`

```py
import os
import re

print("START")

WORKSPACE = os.getenv("WORKSPACE")
GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER = os.getenv("GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER")

FILE = f"{WORKSPACE}/test.py"

with open(FILE, "r") as file:
    content = file.read()

importlib = f'qwe = importlib.import_module("asd-{GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER}")'

content = re.sub(r"#placeholder1", importlib, content)

with open(FILE, "w") as file:
    file.write(content)

print("END")
```

And the workflow file that would perform the operation would look like this:

`workflow.yml`

```yaml
name: ...

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4

      - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: 3.8

      - name: Execute Python script to update test.py file
        run: python .github/scripts/update_file.py
        env:
          WORKSPACE: ${{ github.workspace }}
          GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER: ${{ github.run_number }}

      - run: cat test.py
```

Here is the related and successful [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/7130285822?check_suite_focus=true).

*([workflow file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester44.yml), [update_file.py file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/scripts/update_file.py), [test.py file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/test.py))*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did it using `sed` command and committing a file in github actions.